# Passing useState function as prop to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Im trying to pass a useState function to another prop, but i get the following error:
*Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*

I added the useState function as a handleevent for a buttonClick in the child component, and im assuming that error means it gets called in a loop? Can anyone help me understand the issue here? The code is as follows:

```
    function App() {
        const[personListe, setPersonListe] = useState([
          {
            firstName:'Test',
            lastName:'testing',
            getFullName:function()
            {
                return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
            },
            age:28
            },
        ]);
  
      return (<>
          <Header />
          <h1>Welcome to my react page!</h1>
          <Inputfields personListe={personListe} addPerson={setPersonListe} />
          <PersonList personListe={personListe}/>
        </>
      );
    }
```

Child component(Inputfields.js):

```
export default function Inputfields({personListe}, {addPerson})
{
    function addPerson()
    {
        let firstName = document.getElementById("firstNameID");
        let lastName = document.getElementById("lastNameID");
        let age = document.getElementById("ageID");
        if(firstName.value.length < 1 || lastName.value.length < 1 || age.value.length < 1)
        {
            alert("Please fill out all the fields!");
        }
        else
        {
            addPerson(
                {
                    firstName:firstName.value,
                    lastName:lastName.value,
                    age:age.value
                }
            );
            firstName.value = "";
            lastName.value = "";
            age.value = "";

        }
    }
    return(
        <>
            <Input id="firstNameID" placeholder="First name" /> <br />
            <Input id="lastNameID" placeholder="Last name" /> <br />
            <Input id="ageID" placeholder="Age" type="number" /> <br />
            <Button variant="contained" sx={{marginTop:2}} onClick={addPerson}>Add person</Button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: In the `Inputfields` component you define a function called `addPerson` which recursively calls itself.  Was that intentional?

Comment: I thought i was using the function that is passed in as a parameter? i destructed it and used it in inputfields. Im very green at react, so im not really sure how it is supposed to be passed and used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.  First, you're not destructuring the props correctly.  There is *one* props object passed to the component, not two.  Destructure the two props from that one object:

```
export default function Inputfields({personListe, addPerson})
```

Second, and much more importantly... You never *use* the `addPerson` prop being passed here.  The very first thing your component does is shadow that variable with a new function of the same name:

```
function addPerson()
{
  //...
}
```

Then that function recursively calls itself until the stack overflows.

Don't shadow the variable.  Give the function its own name.  For example:

```
function myAddPerson()
{
  //...
}
```

Then within that function you can call the `addPerson` which was passed to the component.  In the JSX markup call your local function:

```
<Button variant="contained" sx={{marginTop:2}} onClick={myAddPerson}>Add person</Button>
```

Basically this isn't a React issue at all.  This is plain JavaScript.  If you assign a new value to a variable (and defining a function by the same name does exactly that) then the original value is lost.

Comment: Well thats embarassing... didnt notice that i created a function with the same name as the parameter. Thanks for claring it up for me, and explaining to me how to destruct the parameters properly. Much appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

you didn't destruct the props function properly you need to do it like that.

```
export default function Inputfields({personListe,addPerson}) {...rest of your code}
```