# React.js setLoggedin is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know why I keep getting the error message setIsLoggedin is not a function. I'm currently passing down setIsLoggedin as props from App.jsx to Login.jsx component.
When the post request is sent to the backend, I want the setIsLoggedin in to be set as true, and hide the signup component!

App. jsx

```js
function App() {
  const [isLoggedin, setIsLoggedin] = useState(false);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
    <Header />
    <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

        <Route path="/Login" element={ <Login setIsLoggedin={setIsLoggedin}/> }/>  
          <Route path="/SignUp" element={ isLoggedin ? <SignUp/> : null }/>
          <Route path="/Dashboard" element={<Dashboard/> }/> 
          <Route path="/Update" element={<Update/>} />
    </Routes>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Login.jsx

```js
onst Login = ({setIsLoggedin}) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        email: "",
        password: "",
    });

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        localStorage.setItem('token-info', JSON.stringify(values));

        axios.post("http://localhost:4000/signin/auth",values, {
                body: {
                email:'',
                password:''
            },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                if(res){
                    setIsLoggedin(true)
                    navigate('/Dashboard')
                }
            }
             
            )
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    };
    return (
        <div className="sign-up__container">
            <div className="sign-up__title">
                <h1>Sign In</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="input-container">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>email
                <input type="email"
                name="email"
                onChange={(e) => setValues({ ...values, email: e.target.value })}
                ></input>
                </label>

                <label>password
                <input type="password"
                 name="password"
                 onChange={(e) => setValues({ ...values, password: e.target.value })}
                ></input>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" />
                <p>Not registered? <NavLink to="/SignUp">Sign up here!</NavLink> | Forgot your password?</p>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: a good way to find errors is to use ```console.log```

Comment: can you provide error message .

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683494/passing-usestate-function-as-prop-to-another-component

Comment: Hi Zain, I think I figured it out I wasn't returning or console.log anything from the promise in the IF statement, inside the Login component